# Get Value in method from getView of BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, onclick, baseadapter, custom-adapter

This is my Custom Adapter. I have three ImageViews here. I wanted to give onclick for every imageview.

First I have called a method when click on ImageView. In that method I need to replace with the another image. And also need to replace remaining two Imageview images also.

Now When I click on first imageview, method is calling and image also changing for that. But for Remaining two Imageviews, It is showing NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

How to access those ImageViews in that method.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class CustomTestingProductsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public CustomTestingProductsListAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, List<V_APP_PACK_QR_DET_INFO> pack_qr_det_infos) {
    layoutInFlater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.pack_qr_det_infos = pack_qr_det_infos;
    this.curActivity = activity;
    this.mContext = (VilanApplication) VilanApplication.mContext;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pack_qr_det_infos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pack_qr_det_infos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try{
        CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInFlater.inflate(R.layout.tst_ver_prdouct_list_items,null);
            holder.tvProduct = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qc_productName);
            holder.DLSno = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtst_DLSno);
            holder.iv_tst_received = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_received);
            holder.iv_tst_not_received = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_not_received);
            holder.iv_tst_wrong_product = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_wrong_product);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.DLSno.setText(pack_qr_det_infos.get(position).PRODUCTSLNO);
        holder.iv_tst_received.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(position));
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(VilanConstants.TAG,"/Excp @listAdp"+ e.toString());
    }
    return convertView;
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int position){
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
                holder = new CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder();
                holder.iv_tst_received = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_received);
                holder.iv_tst_not_received = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_not_received);
                holder.iv_tst_wrong_product = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_wrong_product);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item Received" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.iv_tst_received.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_received_green);
                holder.iv_tst_not_received.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_received);
                holder.iv_tst_wrong_product.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wrong_product);
                Status = 0 ;
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(VilanConstants.TAG,"/Excp due to"+e.toString());
            }

        }
    };
}


public class ViewHolder{
    private TextView tvProduct;
    private TextView DLSno;
    private ImageView iv_tst_received;
    private ImageView iv_tst_not_received;
    private ImageView iv_tst_wrong_product;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Your getView():

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try{
        CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInFlater.inflate(R.layout.tst_ver_prdouct_list_items,null);
            holder.tvProduct = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_qc_productName);
            holder.DLSno = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtst_DLSno);
            holder.iv_tst_received = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_received);
            holder.iv_tst_not_received = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_not_received);
            holder.iv_tst_wrong_product = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tst_wrong_product);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (CustomTestingProductsListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.DLSno.setText(pack_qr_det_infos.get(position).PRODUCTSLNO);
        holder.iv_tst_received.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item Received" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.iv_tst_received.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_received_green);
                holder.iv_tst_not_received.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_received);
                holder.iv_tst_wrong_product.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wrong_product);
                Status = 0 ;
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(VilanConstants.TAG,"/Excp @listAdp"+ e.toString());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```